# Replacing two ranges in a String simultaneously

Tags: swift

Say you have a string that looks likes this:

```swift
let myStr = "Hello, this is a test String"
```

And you have two Ranges,

```swift
let rangeOne = myStr.range(of: "Hello") //lowerBound: 0, upperBound: 4
let rangeTwo = myStr.range(of: "this")  //lowerBound: 7, upperBound: 10
```

Now you wish to replace those ranges of `myStr` with new characters, that may not be the same length as their original, you end up with this:

```swift
var myStr = "Hello, this is a test String"

let rangeOne = myStr.range(of: "Hello")!
let rangeTwo = myStr.range(of: "this")!

myStr.replaceSubrange(rangeOne, with: "Bonjour") //Bonjour, this is a test String
myStr.replaceSubrange(rangeTwo, with: "ce") //Bonjourceis is a test String
```

Because `rangeTwo` is based on the pre-altered String, it fails to properly replace it.

I could store the length of the replacement and use it to reconstruct a new range, but there is no guarantee that rangeOne will be the first to be replaced, nor that rangeOne will actually be first in the string.

Comment: What is the reason why the ranges can't be replaced and computed sequentially?

Comment: The ranges are stored, and the text replacement happens afterwards

Comment: What is your goal then?

Comment: To be able to replace `myStr` in those two spots, without one replacement making the other not possible

Comment: "Replacing two ranges with two words" and "Replacing two words with two other words" are two different problems.

Comment: The latter is my issue, I have two ranges from a string, and I need to replace the contents that match up with each range with characters of length n, but if the new length doesn't match the old, it invalidates the next range

Comment: You can just calculate the first range, replace it with the first word. Then calculate the second range with the new string, replace it with the second word. Alternatively, just get rid of all the ranges and simply use [replacingOccurrences(of:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412937-replacingoccurrences).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240774/discussion-between-will-and-ricky-mo).

Comment: You are falling in a trap by having "replace a range" in mind. What you want to replace is not a specific range, is a specific word. Don't bother with a precomputed range.

Comment: The question is not a 1:1 representation of the issue I am facing, it is an abstract. The ranges are already there, they're coming from Regex. I'm also not just replacing a word, because some words may occur multiple times in a String, so replacingOccurences(of:) is not an option.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Then you can calculate the difference of the length of the first range and the word you are replacing, and add/subtract the difference to the second range.

Comment: @Will Are you looking to support concurrent editing of a string?

Comment: I believe so, yes

Comment: @Will what you need is to replace the subranges in reverse order

Comment: @Will please check my updated answer.

Comment: @Will Knowing that the edits can be applied in any order, will the edits be ordered after they are applied? For example, the edits will go into a queue and once they are processed, will be labeled in ascending order. Or, will the order always be unknown but the edits must converge to the same string regardless of the order?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is the same as removing multiple items from an array by index in a loop.

**Do it backwards**

First replace `rangeTwo` then `rangeOne`

```
myStr.replaceSubrange(rangeTwo, with: "ce")
myStr.replaceSubrange(rangeOne, with: "Bonjour")
```

An alternative could be also [`replacingOccurrences(of:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412937-replacingoccurrences)

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the range in descending order, then replace backwards, from the end to the start. So that any subsequent replacement will not be affect by the previous replacements. Also, it is safer to use `replacingCharacters` instead of `replaceSubrange` in case when dealing with multi-codepoints characters.

```
let myStr = "Hello, this is a test String"

var ranges = [myStr.range(of: "Hello")!,myStr.range(of: "this")!]
ranges.shuffle()
ranges.sort(by: {$1.lowerBound < $0.lowerBound}) //Sort in reverse order

let newWords : [String] = ["Bonjour","ce"].reversed()
var newStr = myStr

for i in 0..<ranges.count
{
    let range = ranges[i]
    
    //check overlap
    if(ranges.contains(where: {$0.overlaps(range)}))
    {
        //Some range over lap
        throw ...
    }
    let newWord = newWords[i]
    newStr = newStr.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: newWord)
}

print(newStr)
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by shifting the second range based on the length of first the replaced string.

Using your code, here is how you would do it:

```
var myStr = "Hello, this is a test String"

let rangeOne = myStr.range(of: "Hello")!
let rangeTwo = myStr.range(of: "this")!

let shift = "Bonjour".count - "Hello".count

let shiftedTwo = myStr.index(rangeTwo.lowerBound, offsetBy: shift)..<myStr.index(rangeTwo.upperBound, offsetBy: shift)

myStr.replaceSubrange(rangeOne, with: "Bonjour") // Bonjour, this is a test String
myStr.replaceSubrange(shiftedTwo, with: "ce") // Bonjour, ce is a test String
```

Comment: Thanks Adam! This works, but what if "this" is replaced before "Hello"? Then this solution wouldn't work. In my case, there is no guarantee which order things will be replaced in.

Comment: @Will You can sort the ranges before proceed to replace.

Answer (score 1):

My solution ended up being to take the ranges and replacement strings, work backwards and replace

```swift
extension String {
    
    func replacingRanges(_ ranges: [NSRange], with insertions: [String]) -> String {
        var copy = self
        copy.replaceRanges(ranges, with: insertions)
        return copy
    }
    
    mutating func replaceRanges(_ ranges: [NSRange], with insertions: [String]) {
        var pairs = Array(zip(ranges, insertions))
        pairs.sort(by: { $0.0.upperBound > $1.0.upperBound })
        for (range, replacementText) in pairs {
            guard let textRange = Range(range, in: self) else { continue }
            replaceSubrange(textRange, with: replacementText)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Which works out to be useable like this

```swift
var myStr = "Hello, this is a test."
let rangeOne = NSRange(location: 0, length: 5) // “Hello”
let rangeTwo = NSRange(location: 7, length: 4) // “this”
myStr.replaceRanges([rangeOne, rangeTwo], with: ["Bonjour", "ce"])
print(myStr) // Bonjour, ce is a test.
```